# JSF Hibernate decision support

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I like JSF and Hibernate but I have a a problem to make the right decision:

In fact, I have POJOs for Client, House, Problem and son on.
and a Business delegate RentManager. and the programs might help the client to report one or more problems his/her house might have.

I want to get all clients, houses, and problems. Can RentManager do the job of querying the database through POJOs and leave POJOs without collections? if so, all utilities methods will be implemented in RentManager only? or do I have to do a duplication in POJOs? (DRY?)

this is the fragment of the program, I want to get help about

```
class Client{
    //setters/getters/ constructor are here. 
    //I have also client.hbm.xml and works fine
}
class Problem{
    //properties/setters/getters/ constructor 
}

class House{
    //properties/setters/getters/ constructor 
}

class RentManager{
    //List and ArrayList for houses, and problems,
    //and clients + setters/getters/DataModel for these collections

    // addProblem(), updateProblem(), .. 
    // addClient(), updateClient(), ... 
    // addHouse(), updateHouse(), ... 
}
```

with the intension to use RentManager in my controller instead of accessing directly POJOs from controller.
Is this correct approach? or do you guys have a suggestion? thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking in this part: Can RentManager do the job of querying the database through POJOs and leave POJOs without collections? if so, all utilities methods will be implemented in RentManager only?

Comment: To get data from database, we use DAOs and store data into collections[ArrayList, DataModel,...]. So my question is, may I implement that functionality into RentManager and leave POJOs without Collections? or Do I have to include those collections into both POJOs and RentManager? the next question is: do I have to implement utility methods in both RentManager and POJOs?

eg : 
class House{
  /settere/getters/ 
 addHouse(House house){
  ...
 };
}

class RentManager{
      List<House> houses = ...;
      addHouse(House house){...}//?DRY?
}

I guess am clear at least 50%. thanks

Comment: Could you maybe add some pseudo code of what you want to do that you're unsure if you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store your POJO (nor list of POJO') in your RentManager class.
Instead, methods that get entities from database should return POJO or collection of POJO's.
Then you can update your datamodel that is separated class from your RentManager.
The methods that save, update or delete entites should be given POJO as parameter.
e.g:  List getAllclients(), void save(Client client), ...

Another design is to put service methods (save, read,...) in you POJO's.  That's called domain driven design but with such a design you do not need RentManager anymore.